# Generate data set from symbolic 2 variable equation

Tags: matlab, math

Give symbolic equation `abs(sin(x.^2 + 2 *x *y)) == sin(x - 2*y)` I want to create data sets of points. For example for given equation graph would be look like:[image]

What I like to do is generate set of points: [image]

for training neutral network. [image]

For given equation set would be much bigger and would cover all region from negative ten to positive ten for both axis.

Is there any way to generate data set from symbolic equation?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. How are the red points related to your symbolic equation? Are they discrete samples from it? What is the sampling technique – or is that the question? Are the points meant to lie exactly on the curves (your points don't seem to) or are they perturbed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Matlab can do much symbolically, but you can easily find points that approximately solve the equation:

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-10:.004:10); %// create points in [-10,10]x[-10,10]
F=abs(sin(X.^2+2*X.*Y))-sin(X-2*Y); %// calculate residuals
I=abs(F)<1e-2; %// discard points with residual larger than tolerance
x=X(I); %//filter points
y=Y(I);
plot(x,y,'.')
```

[image]

I did have to tune the tolerance and number of points to get good results, and it does use a lot of points, but it should be a good start.